# How to define an input value by default for posting method?

Tags: php, html

I'm making a registration page using form for posting data and want to define a default value in an input tag that I can get that default value when data are posted on the same page. How can I do that without using JavaScript?

```php
// If data have been sent
if(!empty($_POST)){
   $indicative = $_POST['indicative']; 
   $mobile = $_POST['mobile']; 
   $number = $indicative.$mobile;
   echo "Your phone number is: " . $number;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="indicative" value="+33" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="tel" name="mobile">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I expect the indicative default data value to be sent but I got an error like "Undefined index: indicative"

Comment: _Disabled_ form controls do not become part of the form submission data set. Use `readonly` instead, if you want the user to be able to _see_ the value that will be submitted, but not (directly) change it, or a hidden input field if you don’t want them to see it in the first place.

Comment: As 04FS suggested, use read-only attribute to restrict user from modifying the value. - <input type="text" name="indicative" value="+33" readonly>
If you give disabled, the value wont be submited by the form,instead it will be ignored. You are getting the Undefined index: indicative error beacuse of the disabled attribute

Comment: Thanks both of you it worked using readonly attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **readonly** and **disabled** attributes have superficially similar behaviours — they both stop the user from editing the value of the  element. However, there is a big difference. The value of the **readonly** element will be included when the form is submitted to the server. The value of a **disabled** element will not be submitted to the server.

Read more: https://html.com/attributes/input-readonly/#ixzz5kUcCxk9a

You can use readonly to appear that in `$_POST`

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="indicative" value="+33" readonly/>
  <input type="tel" name="mobile" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```